# wget download for offline viewing including absolute references

Tags: wget

I'm trying to download an entire webpage using the following command

```
wget -p -k www.myspace.com/
```

This does download the page and any images or scripts under that directory, but I'm trying to figure out how to download that page for completely offline viewing. How would I get every image, script, and style sheet linked within the source for www.myspace.com including external links?

Comment: I hope you have a massive harddrive.  myspace.com isn't exactly a small site.

Comment: I'm not anything recursive which is why i don't have -r or -m. I want a mirror of that one page including an offline version of all external  content references. Also it's not myspace, I just used that as an example since it has external references for images

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
wget -e robots=off -H -p -k http://www.myspace.com/
```

The -H or --span-hosts flag is necessary for a complete mirror, as the page is likely to include content on hosts outside the www.myspace.com domain. Ignore robots for good measure.

Comment: the -H was all I was missing. Thanks for that

Comment: I know this is super old, but I found it helpful today and thought I'd add that you may need to [limit spanning with -D](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Spanning-Hosts.html) to avoid grabbing unwanted files

Answer (score -1):

`wget -mk http://www.myspace.com/`

works for me. I am not sure about myspace or whatever site you are trying to mirror specifically, but sometimes you have to pass in some other options to get around the no-robots policy. I am not going to say how to do that because it means you are doing something you shouldn't be doing. Although it is definitely possible.

Comment: I'm not trying to mirror the entire site. I want a mirror of that one page including an offline version of all external content references. I know how to have it ignore robots, but the site I'm crawling doesn't have a robots policy against wget